# How to elegantly "reframe" a numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, scipy

I'm using a `numpy.array` as a data buffer, and I'm looking for an elegant way to `reframe` it so that it keeps a portion of the initial data, depending on new framing conditions (the buffer may have `shrunk`, `expanded`, `shifted` or a combination of `shift` + the 2 former)

`Reframe` may not be the proper term here. But the example below will hopefully make it clear:

For simplicity I'll use `False` to illustrate an empty `reframed` array element:

```
import numpy as np

# Init buffer
data = 10 * np.arange(6) + 10 # dummy data for this example
# Result: array([10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60]) #
```

Shrinking the buffer:

```
# shift start by 1 to the right, and end by 1 to the left
reframe(data,1,-1) # basically doing: buffer[1:-1]
# Desired Result = array([20, 30, 40, 50]) #
```

Expand the buffer:

```
# shift start by 2 to the left, and end by 1 to the 
reframe(data,-2,1)
# Desired Result: array([False, False, 10, 20, 30, 40, 50, 60, False]) #
```

Shift the buffer left or right + expand:

```
# shift start by 2 to the right, and end by 4 to the right 
reframe(data,2,4)
# Desired Result: array([30, 40, 50, 60, False, False, False, False]) #
```

Again in this example I used`False` where I'd expect a new empty `reframed` array element. This could be `np.empty`, or `np.NaN`, etc...

To achieve my goal I wrote the following:

```
import numpy as np

def reframe(data,start,end):

    # Shrinking: new array is a substet of original
    if start >= 0 and end <=0:
        if start > 0 and end < 0:
            return data[start:end]
        if start > 0:
            return data[start:]
        return data[:end]

    # Expand, new array fully contains original
    elif start <= 0 and end >= 0:
        new = np.zeros(data.shape[0] + end - start).astype(data.dtype)
        new[abs(start):data.shape[0]+2] = data
        return new

    # Shift, new array may have a portion of old
    else:
        new = np.zeros((data.shape[0]-start+end)).astype(data.dtype)

        # Shift Right
        if start > 0:
            new[:data.shape[0]-start] = data[start:]
            return new

        # Shift Left
        if end < 0:
            new[:data.shape[0]+end] = data[::-1][abs(end):]
            return new[::-1]
```

Testing:

```
print reframe(data,1,-1) # [20 30 40 50]
print reframe(data,-2,1) # [ 0  0 10 20 30 40 50 60  0]
print reframe(data,2,4)  # [30 40 50 60  0  0  0  0]
```

So this works for my purposes, but I was hoping there would be something a little more elegant.

Also in my real life application my arrays are in the hundreds of thousands, so efficiency is a must.

Comment: Only for 1D array or do you also want to "reframe" ND arrays?

Comment: @MSeifert in my current use case I need to "reframe" both a 1d and an 2d array, but in the 2d array's case I only care if it is along the 1st axis. So if you have a solution that applies only to 1d arrays I don't mind applying it the 2d array along the 1st axis element wise

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import numpy as np

def reframe(x, start, end, default=0):
    shape = list(x.shape)
    orig_length = shape[0]
    shape[0] = length = end - start

    old_start = max(0, start)
    old_end = min(end, length + 1, orig_length)
    new_start = -start if start < 0 else 0
    new_end = new_start + old_end - old_start

    x_new = np.empty(shape, dtype=x.dtype)
    x_new[:] = default
    x_new[new_start:new_end] = x[old_start:old_end]
    return x_new

x = np.arange(6) + 1

x_new = reframe(x, 1, 4)
print('1. ', x_new)

x_new = reframe(x, -4, 4)
print('2. ', x_new)

x_new = reframe(x, 1, 7)
print('3. ', x_new)

x_new = reframe(x, -1, 9, default=4)
print('4. ', x_new)

x = np.arange(100).reshape(20, 5) + 1
x_new = reframe(x, -1, 2)
print('5. ', x_new)
```

Output:

```
1. [2 3 4]
2. [0 0 0 0 1 2 3 4]
3. [2 3 4 5 6 0]
4. [4 1 2 3 4 5 6 4 4 4]
5. [[ 0  0  0  0  0]
    [ 1  2  3  4  5]
    [ 6  7  8  9 10]]
```

I believe this meets the requirements. The main part that is unclear to me in the question is why the start is at 10 and the end is 15, instead of say 0 and 5. This function is 0-indexed. Negative indexes for start means that you want to expand to the leftside from the start. Also, it is not inclusive since that is generally how python/numpy works.

It is hard to know what the default value should be since I do not know the type of the array. Therefore, I added a default parameter, which will initialize the array.

Comment: You're right, the start/end times are confusing the issue.  I edited my question to completely removed them, and instead just treat the values as offsets for start and end of the array.

Comment: I see you updates the question with a solution. Can you please explain why the reframe I wrote doesn't meet exactly what you need?

Comment: The solution I added is was to illustrate the behavior I needed. Your solution works an is more elegant than my pile of if statements. :)